# Getting a 403 error when invoking POST call to ApiGateway from static S3 hosted website javascript function

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have the following javascript that is supposed to invoke a POST call from within a static site hosted on AWS S3:

```
function invokeAWSAPI(e) {
    e.preventDefault();           
    var name = $("#form-name").val();
    var phone = $("#form-phone").val();
    var email = $("#form-email").val();
    var msg = $("#form-message").val();
    var data = {
       name : name,
       phone : phone,
       email : email,
       msg : msg
     };
    $.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url : "https://***.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/contactform",
      dataType: "json",
      crossDomain: "true",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      success: function () {
        alert("Successful");
        document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
    location.reload();
      },
      error: function () {
        alert("unsuccessful");
      }});
}
```

I have the endpoint tested and working within the API Gateway, Postman, and the Lambda function that the endpoint triggers. I know all that works fine, but it's only when it is called from this javascript function that I get the following error:

```
<Error>
  <Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code>
  <Message>The specified method is not allowed against this resource.</Message>
  <Method>POST</Method>
  <ResourceType>OBJECT</ResourceType>
  <RequestId>16PS1ACA5HK2SWEE</RequestId>
  <HostId>DL8hUA0bd1jsj0iBQe1maR94/RW6YFecSzAuEs+R0PDn9hDRxWyD9L4eacJzcDRVD3si6d8XCzc= 
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

Based on the research I have done so far, this indicates that it is trying to perform the POST call on the S3 bucket itself, but I can't see how that would be the case. Any help getting this function to work properly would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where does this error message orginate from? Is it logged by CloudWatch? Is it logged by your error handler?

If it comes from CloudWatch, a simple thing might be that your api gateway only allows the http method  "post" but you're sending a "put".

Comment: The function used to be POST but even after changing it to PUT, the error still complains about POST not being allowed. I think the error originates from S3 because I previously had a 405 error that I fixed by making a change to the Cloudfront distribution

Comment: Is there a difference when you try to access the s3 website-domain compared against the url of cloudfront?

Answer (score 0):

It is about CORS setting of your S3 bucket. I spent a while trying to solve it . There is a CORS section in the bucket permissions tab.

You can use example police from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html?icmpid=docs_s3_hp_cors_editor_page

There are wildcards for methods set by default, you can leave it as it is or choose methods you want. If you add url of your bucket to "AllowedOrigin" header in the police it should work.